# How to hide text with .CSS?

Tags: html, css, xml

How to hide text with .CSS?

Here is our code.

```
<footer>    
      <p>Our Company, OFFICE: 555-1212</p>
      <div class="footer_License"><span>License #:</span> RB-21781</div> 
                          <p><a href="https://www.example.com/terms-of-service" target="_blank">Terms</a>
<a href="http://www.HideThis.com/real_estate_agents_sales_representatives.html#leads" target="_blank">Leads</a> by
<a href="http://www.sample.com/" target="_blank">HideThis<span id="hide-logo"><img src="/modules/free_home_valuation/images/Logo.png" alt="HideThis" /></span></a></p>
</footer>
```

We want to Hide all but:

Our Company, OFFICE: 555-1212

License #:RB-25555
Terms of Service  Privacy Policy

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to hide? Ran your code and it shows exactly what you want, is it that you only want to hide the images?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail your expectations? Does `#hide-logo{display:none;}` suit your needs? Or if just hide the last link `footer > a:last-of-type {display:none;}`

Comment: Hey @Hawaii - following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. ***Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question.*** If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). Remember, too: you can upvote any answers you found helpful (you can also upvote and checkmark the same answer, if desired.) *Thanks!*

Comment: @Hawaii This question is still open. Please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to assign a class to the element(s) you wish to hide.

Because there are multiple elements, and some text that is not inside a container (such as the `a` tag), I wrapped the elements you wish to hide in a span, and added a class (that I called `hideme`) onto that span.

If you ever wish to remove the hide class and display the information, I added a button and some javascript code to show how easily that is done.

```js
//Look closely - this is not jQuery
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
$('#showme').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const allHidden = $$('.hideme');
   allHidden.forEach((el) => {
      el.classList.remove('hideme');
   });
   console.log(e.target.innerText);
   
});
```

```css
.hideme{display: none;}
```

```html
<footer>
    <p>Our Company, OFFICE: 555-1212</p>
    <div class="footer_License">
        <span>License #:</span> RB-21781
    </div> 
    <p>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/terms-of-service" target="_blank">Terms of Service </a> &#124; 
        <a href="https://www.example.com/privacy-policy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> &#124; 
        <span class="hideme">
            <a href="http://www.HideThis.com" target="_blank">Leads</a> by 
            <a href="http://www.sample.com/" target="_blank"> HideThis
                <span id="hide-logo"><img src="Logo.png" alt="HideThis" /></span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </p>
</footer>
<button id="showme">Show Me</button>
```

#### Note:

Remember that HTML is designed around the [box model](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_boxmodel.asp), which means that the entire web page is a box (container) that contains other boxes, which contain other boxes. Everything is either content (text/images), or a container, or is inside a container. Your job is to design what is inside of what so that you can best arrange/display it on the page, or show/hide it as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This code:

```
<style>
footer > p:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.footer_License {
  display: none;
}
footer > p > a:first-child
 {     
    display: none;
 }
</style>
```

Here, `first-child` property use to select the first element cild of any html element and `>` is use to go on the child or should I say to select the Child element of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
footer > p:nth-of-type(2) > :not(:nth-child(-n + 2)) {
    display: none;
    /* visibility:hidden; */
}
```

This will hide any element in the second paragraph but the first and second children.

Choose "display" or "visibility" depending on what you mean by "hide"

```css
footer > p:nth-of-type(2) > :not(:nth-child(-n + 2)) {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<footer>    
      <p>Our Company, OFFICE: 555-1212</p>
      <div class="footer_License"><span>License #:</span> RB-21781</div> 
                          <p><a href="https://www.example.com/terms-of-service" target="_blank">Terms</a>
<a href="http://www.HideThis.com/real_estate_agents_sales_representatives.html#leads" target="_blank">Leads</a> by
<a href="http://www.sample.com/" target="_blank">HideThis<span id="hide-logo"><img src="/modules/free_home_valuation/images/Logo.png" alt="HideThis" /></span></a></p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

all answers are difficult you have to only use a one line of code display:none to hide and display:block in